# Crude death rate per 100 subjects per year with missing values and different lengths of follow-up

Tags: missing-data, mortality

We need to compute the crude death rate per 100 subjects per year. We have a dataset with 383 observations. The death status is available for every subject, but the length of follow up is different for each subjects and for 45 of them we don't have this value.

Given the crude death rate formula (tell me if is wrong):
$$\frac{\frac{n.deaths}{n.subjects}*100}{observation.years}$$

Which population (n.deaths and n.subjects) should I use? All of them or just the ones for which I have the follow up length? Regarding the years of observation which value should I use? the longest follow-up?

Thanks

UPDATE: I think my formula wasn't appropriate. In case of variable follow-up lengths at the denominator the sum of the years of observation of each subject should be used. So the formula becomes like this:

$$\frac{n.deaths}{\sum observation.periods}*100$$

The only remaining question is whether should I count or not the people for which I don't have the length of the follow up in the number of deaths.

Comment: Observation years would normally be the average of observation years across all subjects (or alternatively instead of n.subjects*observation.years you could use the sum of observation years across all subjects).

Comment: n.deaths & observation.years are sufficient statistics for the exponential distribution. More interesting: what to do regarding missing observation years for some subjects? If the missingness is *definitely* of whether patients died, then it might be okay to use only subjects with non-missing data. If there is any reason it might not be independent, then something else is needed (e.g. treating it as interval censored).

Comment: Yesterday I was updating the question but then apparently I forgot to submit the changes!